# Solving integral of (1-u)^n log(-log(1-u)) du?

Tags: integration, logarithms

I am currently working on finding a closed-form equation for the variance of the ordered data of the three-parameter Weibull distribution. One method has been proposed, but the published solution is using numerical integration. A much faster solution would need to simplify the expression, which lead me to this expression.

Is there a solution in closed-form for this equation in which $n \in \mathbb{N} >1$?

$$
\int_0^1 (1-u)^n (\log(-\log(1-u)))^2 \mathrm{d}u
$$

If not, is there a good approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the substitution $x = \ln\left(\frac{1}{1-u} \right)$ your integral is equal to
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x(n+1)} \ln^2(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
which by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/394227/695196) gives you
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 (1-u)^n \ln^2\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-u}\right)\right)\, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{n+1}\left(\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} + \left(\gamma+ \ln(n+1)\right)^2\right)}
$$

Comment: Wow! I'm impressed! Many thanks!