# Solving $\int_0^1(1-u)^{(n-i)} u^i \log(-\log(1-u))^2 du$?

Tags: integration, logarithms

This problem is similar to the one solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317847/solving-integral-of-1-un-log-log1-u-du) except for an additional term in $u$:

$$
\int_0^1 (1-u)^{(n-i)} u^i (\log(-\log(1-u)))^2 \mathrm{d}u
$$

in which $0 \le i \le n$ and both $i$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. In the specific case where $i=0$ we are back to the solution given in the above link. However, is there a solution in this more general problem?

This equation shows up when trying to solve an estimator for the Weibull distribution.

Comment: Seems related to: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-kx}\log^2 x\,dx$$ for $k\in\mathbb N.$ Specifically, if you substitute  $u=1-e^{-x}.$ But I don’t know how to do this integral, either. It just looks a smidge easier.

Comment: The title say $n-1$ where the body says $n-i.$

Comment: Actually, you can get it into your original form by just expanding $$u^i=(1-(1-u))^i=\sum_{j=0}^{i}\binom ij (-1)^j(1-u)^j$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ThomasAndrews mentions in his comment, you can obtain this case from the linked answer as follows:
$$
\int_0^1 (1-u)^{(n-i)} u^i \ln^2(-\ln(1-u)) \mathrm{d}u =\sum_{j=0}^{i}\binom{i}{j} (-1)^j \int_{0}^{1} (1-u)^{n-i+j} \ln^2(-\ln(1-u)) \mathrm{d}u
$$
and after some direct simplifications, this results in
$$
\boxed{\int_0^1 (1-u)^{(n-i)} u^i \ln^2(-\ln(1-u)) \mathrm{d}u = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \frac{i! (n-i)!}{(n+1)!} +\sum_{k=1}^{i+1} \binom{i}{k-1} (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\left(\gamma + \ln(n-i+k) \right)^2}{(n-i+k)}}
$$
which I doubt can be simplified further.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.